# Change submit button text based on radio-button value

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

How to change submit button text based on which radio-button is active?

Here is my code, but it does not work. It changes text only once.

I have two radio-buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="build-team" class="choose" value="build" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="build-team" class="choose" value="show" /> No
<button class="show-result" data-chooseyes="Yes" data-chooseno="No">Yes</button>
```

And I have script:

```
$(document).on('click', '.choose', function() {
    var target = $('.show-result');
    if ($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') {
      target.html(target.data('chooseyes'));
    }
    else {
      target.html(target.data('chooseno'));
    }
})
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9fgfkusx/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.choose', function() {
    var target = $('.show-result');
      target.html($(this).val());
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="build-team" class="choose" value="Yes" /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="build-team" class="choose" value="No" /> No
<button class="show-result" data-chooseyes="Yes" data-chooseno="No">Yes</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.opt').click(function(){
  $('#button').html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="opt" name="opt" type="radio" value="Yes" checked="checked">Yes
<input class="opt" name="opt" type="radio" value="No">No
<button id="button" type="submit">Yes</button>
```

This is the easiest answer, no added attributes, only clean HTML + jQuery, it is also important to realize that there must always be a radio selected/checked by default, if not, you would have to validate the field and validating a radio is not cool haha :) have a nice day!